# Query using .or and .link together doesn't work

Tags: java, objectbox

I'm building an ObjectBox query on Android using a series of if statements:

```
QueryBuilder<CustomerData> qb = CustomersBox.query();
            qb.contains(CustomerData_.NAME, SearchTerm);
            if (SearchTerms.contains("AGENT"))
                qb.or().contains(CustomerData_.AGENT, SearchTerm);
            if (SearchTerms.contains("CUSTNUM"))
                qb.or().contains(CustomerData_.CUSTNUM, SearchTerm);
```

If left as above, it works fine with a simple `qb.build().find();`

Now I'm linking to a OneToMany object for more search terms:

```
            if (SearchTerms.contains("DELIVERYNOTES")) {
                qb.or().link(CustomerData_.Products).contains(CustomerProduct_.DELY1, SearchTerm);
```

However this dies with an `IllegalStateException: An operator is pending. Use operators like and() and or() only between two conditions.`

Is it not possible to make the linked query conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is currently not supported. Calling `QueryBuilder.link(property)` returns a separate `QueryBuilder` instance.

See https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/497 that requests this feature. Please thumbs up!

Comment: If ObjectBox was honest in their docs about what is not possible then probably the vast majority of current users would use .txt to store their data )). I mean you have put immense effort to make something nice but when you want to use it in an advanced way, all the library falls down like a sand castle.